# High frequency Updates,Inserts on table,multiple access simultaneously

Tags: mysql, memcached

I have a table that will be accessed by thousands at a time.The data entered by each user may update a particular row or insert a row depending on an algo.I want to store the entire table in main memory and write to db at 0000 hrs as the records are of no use later on.I have read about memcache.Will it help?

Comment: Memcached uses key value pairs, it's not a table at all. Do you mean [Memory tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html)?

Comment: Its just that I want the updates and inserts to be temporary and not written to disk.But accessible to all active users.Like a normal table but stored in main memory at all times.Im not very sure about memcached..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the requirements that you've stated, it sounds like you want to use MySQL's [Memory Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html). Memory tables have fast access and are not written to disk. They're for transient information like sessions and caches.

> Operations involving transient, non-critical data such as session
>   management or caching. When the MySQL server halts or restarts, the
>   data in MEMORY tables is lost.

You get full relational support, with updates, inserts, and selects, accessible to all sessions.

Memcached could be used, but you'd have to implement the caching in code. If you are using a framework, it might already support this in the base model, or you could implement it there.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add - you can just add more memory to INNODB Bufferpool (if you use it). INNDB will use this memory to store information in memory and also save in disk.
Memcache can be used to store computed columns, pre-generated HTML, etc...